# Multidimensional Associative Arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Started getting into C# from JS and PHP. I am getting used to the strict use of data types and I am struggling to figure out how to declare multidimensional associative array of different data types.

Like for example in PHP one would probably do something like this

```
 $roomDiscount["apartment"][0]["minDaysOfStay"] = 10;
 $roomDiscount["apartment"][0]["discount"] = 0.3;

 $roomDiscount["apartment"][1]["minDaysOfStay"] = 15;
 $roomDiscount["apartment"][1]["discount"] = 0.35;

 $roomDiscount["apartment"][2]["minDaysOfStay"] = 16;
 $roomDiscount["apartment"][2]["discount"] = 0.5;

 $roomDiscount["presidential suite"][0]["minDaysOfStay"] = 10;
 $roomDiscount["presidential suite"][0]["discount"] = 0.1;

 $roomDiscount["presidential suite"][1]["minDaysOfStay"] = 15;
 $roomDiscount["presidential suite"][1]["discount"] = 0.15;

 $roomDiscount["presidential suite"][2]["minDaysOfStay"] = 16;
 $roomDiscount["presidential suite"][2]["discount"] = 0.2;
```

So far I have been struggling with Dictionaries

```
private static void SkiTripWithDictionariesArrays()
        {
            int daysOfStay = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string typeOfAccomodation = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();
            string review = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();

            Dictionary<string, double> roomPrices = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            Dictionary<string, object> roomDiscounts = new Dictionary<string, object>(); // <---- thats the bugger
            Dictionary<string, double> reviewAdjustment = new Dictionary<string, double>();

           
            //populate room prices
            roomPrices.Add("room for one person", 18);
            roomPrices.Add("apartment", 25);
            roomPrices.Add("president apartment", 35);

        }
```

Comment: Your PHP code would be more akin to a `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, double>>>`, though it would make a lot more sense to define classes that match the data you want to store.

Comment: Can you tell me what the first number indexing represents? For example the 2 in `$roomDiscount["presidential suite"][2]`.

Comment: The 2 is essentially just the auto index of the inner array, in essence I could put the value of the minDaysOfStay there and compare directly with the user inputs

Comment: But what does it represent? Why do you have `$roomDiscount["presidential suite"][0]`, `$roomDiscount["presidential suite"][1]`, and `$roomDiscount["presidential suite"][2]`?

Comment: Because otherwise the values will get overwritten if i go 
 
`$roomDiscount["presidential suite"]["minDaysOfStay"] = 10;`
`$roomDiscount["presidential suite"]["minDaysOfStay"] = 15;`

then  presidential suite -> minDaysOfStay = 15;

Comment: But why don't you want the values to be overwritten? Why is there this distinction? It clearly represents some aspect of your data or you would be happy that it gets overwritten.

Comment: I've considered that perhaps 0, 1, and 2 each represent a separate "presidential suite" room. Or perhaps it represents a history of changes to the "presidential suite" class of room.

Comment: In essence it represents a discount percentage based on the number of days of stay in a specific room type.

E.g. if the person stays in an apartment less than 10 days the discount would be 30%, if its between 10 and 15 days than the discount would be 35% so on and so forth. In the end I want to compare the days of stay against the room type and fetch the discount based on the number of days of stay.

maybe a for loop with like` (customer.roomtype.numberofdays < actualnumberofdays => totalPrice -= totalPrice * discount)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current PHP code is like this:

```
$roomDiscount["apartment"][0]["minDaysOfStay"] = 10;
```

It is close to this kind of structure in C#:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, double>>>
```

Declaring such an object probably isn't a good way of going about it. Instead you should define class objects instead. The example I give below is for illustrative purposes only, and isn't necessarily the best way to do this (there are many different approaches to this situation):

```
public class RoomDiscount
{
    public int MinDaysOfStay {get;set;}
    public double Discount {get;set;}
}

public class RoomDiscounts
{
    public List<RoomDiscount> DiscountBands {get;set;}
}
```

Usage:

```
Dictionary<string, RoomDiscounts> discountDetails = new Dictionary<string, RoomDiscounts>();
discountDetails["apartment"] = new RoomDiscounts {
    DiscountBands = new List<RoomDiscount> {
        new RoomDiscount {
            MinDaysOfStay = 10,
            Discount = 0.3
        },            
        new RoomDiscount {
            MinDaysOfStay = 15,
            Discount = 0.35
        },            
        new RoomDiscount {
            MinDaysOfStay = 16,
            Discount = 0.5
        }
    }
};

string room = "apartment";
int daysOfStay = 26;
double discount = discountDetails[room].DiscountBands.OrderByDescending(b => b.MinDaysOfStay).FirstOrDefault(b => daysOfStay >= b.MinDaysOfStay)?.Discount ?? 0;
```

Again, this is just an example of one way you could organise your data in a more strongly-typed fashion. Note that this will throw an exception if the room type isn't defined, so you could use [`TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-5.0) to retrieve the details from the dictionary.

Comment: That's a great explanation @John. Thanks for taking time. I mean best case scenario  one would probably be working with a database for such things, but lets take it one step at a time. That gives me a perspective on things in c# and would do for now. As you said there would probably be a ton of solutions and approaches

Comment: I did look at the other similar question on here and in good ol' uncle Google, just couldnt get a hang of it. Also I read on one of them that this class approach seems more memory consuming or something of the sort. Dare you give your input on this matter :)

Comment: @NikolayKremenliev I typically see programming as a balancing act. That is to say, you can write something that's easy to maintain, but it might not be the most efficient thing ever, or you can write highly efficient code, but it might be difficult to follow and thus difficult to maintain. Using statically and strongly typed code helps prevent runtime errors due to the data being in a different state to how we expect, but it sometimes makes things less flexible. On the other hand, the data structure is easier to follow, to the code is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to consume memory much differently to what your PHP code does. You're essentially storing the same information in different formats. The benefit of using classes here (with regards to memory) is that we're not storing string values for the MinDaysOfStay and Discount variable names.